# I can't create a date partitioned table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create a partition table in PostgreSQL using the query below and store data by date (01~31).

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    aaa varchar(4) NOT NULL, 
    bbb int4 NOT NULL,
    ccc timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_test" PRIMARY KEY (aaa, bbb)
) PARTITION BY RANGE(to_char(ccc, 'DD'));

CREATE TABLE test_01 PARTITION OF test FOR VALUES FROM ('01') TO ('02');
...
CREATE TABLE test_31 PARTITION OF test FOR VALUES FROM ('31') TO ('32');
```

However, the following error occurs in the `PARTITION BY RANGE(to_char(ccc, 'DD'))`.

```
functions in partition key expression must be marked IMMUTABLE
```

How do I partition a table by date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an expression as the partition key did not allow the use of primary key constraints. Therefore, we removed the private key constraint from the root table and added the constraint to the leaf table.

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    aaa varchar(4) NOT NULL, 
    bbb int4 NOT NULL,
    ccc timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) PARTITION BY RANGE(EXTRACT(DAY FROM ccc));

DO $$ 
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..31 LOOP
        EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE test_' || i || ' PARTITION OF test FOR VALUES FROM (' || i || ') TO (' || i+1 || ')';
        EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE test_' || i || ' ADD PRIMARY KEY (aaa, bbb)';
    END LOOP;
END $$;
```